# Kubernetes Rewrite Ingress returns 404 when fetching

Tags: url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a question concerning setting up an ingress. First of all. Situation:
My Application is running on my server my.server.ip:32252/csv and i am able to select and download my files.
The ingress is also working. Here is the Code

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite-ch
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.server.at
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 6000
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
  tls:
  - secretName: mysecret
    hosts:
    - my.server.at
```

And the Application is available under https://my.server.at/something/csv

**My Problem is** that, when I hit the button in my application it will redirect me to some new links. But this only works with http and the port number.
Could it be a rewriting “problem”?
As example

- Working: Open   http://my.server.ip:32252/csv , then a click on my application brings me to http://my.server.ip:32252/sensor_list
- Failing: Open https://my.server.at/something/csv then a click on my application brings me an error

[image]

Suggestions and Ideas are welcome.
All the best and hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Please change following section your Ingress file:

```
 tls:
  - secretName: mysecret
    hosts:
    - my.server.at
```

to :

```
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.server.at
  - secretName: mysecret
```

Also add following annotations into Ingress definition file:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-secret: mysecret
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
```

Please take a look:  [ingress-kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1701),  [nginx-ingress-annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/).